# helm yaml iterate causes nil pointer

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-cronjob

I am trying to iterate over jobsContainer array to generate multiple instances in the cronjob I am creating.
Ny values.yaml look like the below:

```
jobContainers:
  - cleaner1:
    env:
      keepRunning: false
    logsPath: /nfs/data_etl/logs

  - cleaner2:
    env:
      keepRunning: false
    logsPath: /nfs/data_etl/logs
```

and my template cronJob.yaml looks like:

```
      {{- range $job, $val := .Values.jobContainers }}
        - image: "{{ $image.repository }}:{{ $image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ $image.pullPolicy }}
          name: {{ $job }}
          env:
            - name: KEEP_RUNNING
              value: "{{ .env.keepRunning }}"
          volumeMounts:
          - name: {{ .logsPathName }}
            mountPath: /log

        restartPolicy: Never
      {{- end }}
```

helm install returns the following error:

> executing "/templates/cronjob.yaml" at <.env.keepRunning>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.keepRunning

My cronjob.Yaml is below:

```
    {{- $image := .Values.image }}

apiVersion: batch/v1beta1

kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    chart: ni-filecleaner
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: {{ .Release.Name }}
            cron: {{ .Values.filesjob.jobName }}
        spec:
          containers:
          {{- range $job, $val := .Values.jobContainers }}
            - image: "{{ $image.repository }}:{{ $image.tag }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ $image.pullPolicy }}
              name: {{ $job }}
              env:
                - name: KEEP_RUNNING
                  value: "{{ $val.env.keepRunning }}"
                - name: FILE_RETENTION_DAYS
                  value: "{{ .env.retentionPeriod }}"
                - name: FILE_MASK
                  value: "{{ .env.fileMask }}"
                - name: ID
                  value: "{{ .env.id }}"
              volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /data
                name: {{ .dataPathName }}
              - name: {{ .logsPathName }}
                mountPath: /log
  
            restartPolicy: Never
            volumes:
              - name: {{ .dataPathName }}
                nfs:
                  server: {{ .nfsIp }}
                  path: {{ .dataPath }}
              - name: {{ .logsPathName }}
                nfs:
                  server: {{ .nfsIp }}
                  path: {{ .logsPath }}
          {{- end }}

  schedule: "{{ .Values.filesjob.schedule }}"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: {{ .Values.filesjob.successfulJobsHistoryLimit }}
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: {{ .Values.filesjob.failedJobsHistoryLimit }}

  {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}

  nodeSelector:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
  {{- end }}
```

The full values.yaml is below:

```
    replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: app.corp/ni-etl-filecleaner
  tag: "3.0.3.1"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

jobContainers:
  - processed:
      env:
        keepRunning: false
        fileMask: ne*.*
        retentionPeriod: 3
        id: processed
      jobName: processed
      dataPathName: path-to-clean-processed
      logsPathName: path-logfiles-processed
      dataPath: /nfs/data_etl/loader/processed
      logsPath: /nfs/data_etl/logs
      nfsIp: ngs.corp

  - incoming:
      env:
        keepRunning: false
        fileMask: ne*.*
        retentionPeriod: 3
        id: incoming
      jobName: incoming
      dataPathName: path-to-clean-incoming
      logsPathName: path-logfiles-incoming
      dataPath: /nfs/data_etl/loader/incoming
      logsPath: /nfs/data_etl/logs
      nfsIp: ngs.corp

resources: {}

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

Comment: Use `$val.env.keepRunning` instead of `.env.keepRunning`

Comment: thanks but no still the same error

Comment: Can't post code in comment. So added a answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some indentation issue with both of your values file and template file. Here, is the correct template and values file.

```
{{- $image := .Values.image }}
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    chart: ni-filecleaner
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: {{ .Release.Name }}
            cron: {{ .Values.filesjob.jobName }}
        spec:
          containers:
          {{- range $job, $val := .Values.jobContainers }}
            - image: "{{ $image.repository }}:{{ $image.tag }}"
              imagePullPolicy: {{ $image.pullPolicy }}
              name: "{{ $job }}"
              env:
                - name: KEEP_RUNNING
                  value: "{{ $val.env.keepRunning }}"
                - name: FILE_RETENTION_DAYS
                  value: "{{ $val.env.retentionPeriod }}"
                - name: FILE_MASK
                  value: "{{ $val.env.fileMask }}"
                - name: ID
                  value: "{{ $val.env.id }}"
              volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /data
                name: {{ $val.dataPathName }}
              - name: {{ $val.logsPathName }}
                mountPath: /log
          restartPolicy: Never
          volumes:
            - name: {{ $val.dataPathName }}
              nfs:
                server: {{ $val.nfsIp }}
                path: {{ $val.dataPath }}
            - name: {{ $val.logsPathName }}
              nfs:
                server: {{ $val.nfsIp }}
                path: {{ $val.logsPath }}
          {{- end }}

  schedule: "{{ .Values.filesjob.schedule }}"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: {{ .Values.filesjob.successfulJobsHistoryLimit }}
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: {{ .Values.filesjob.failedJobsHistoryLimit }}

  {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}

  nodeSelector:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
  {{- end }}
```

```
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: app.corp/ni-etl-filecleaner
  tag: "3.0.3.1"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

filesjob:
  name: cleaner

jobContainers:
  - processed:
    env:
      keepRunning: false
      fileMask: ne*.*
      retentionPeriod: 3
      id: processed
    jobName: processed
    dataPathName: path-to-clean-processed
    logsPathName: path-logfiles-processed
    dataPath: /nfs/data_etl/loader/processed
    logsPath: /nfs/data_etl/logs
    nfsIp: ngs.corp

  - incoming:
    env:
      keepRunning: false
      fileMask: ne*.*
      retentionPeriod: 3
      id: incoming
    jobName: incoming
    dataPathName: path-to-clean-incoming
    logsPathName: path-logfiles-incoming
    dataPath: /nfs/data_etl/loader/incoming
    logsPath: /nfs/data_etl/logs
    nfsIp: ngs.corp

resources: {}

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

Comment: still doesn't work with this error now: executing "/templates/cronjob.yaml" at <$val.env.keepRunning>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.keepRunning

Comment: Can you share the full YAML of the CronJob and and Values file so I can test the entire YAML?

Comment: Updated the answer. There were some indentation issue with both values file and tempalte file.